# Disable cache with Midori on Raspberry Pi

Tags: caching, raspberry-pi, midori

I use the Midori web browser on my Raspberry Pi.

The page is reloaded automatically, but it doesn't reload pictures when I change it on the server (they are cached somewhere).

How do I disable this?